# filter keys in JSON using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I am having a complex nested json

```
{
...
"key1": {
   "key2" : [
       { ...
         "base_score" :4.5
       }
    ]
"key3": {

       "key4": [
         { ...
           "base_score" : 0.5 
           ...
         }
       ]

       }
...

    }
}
```

There maybe multiple "base_score" in the json("base_score" path is unknown) and the corresponding value will be a number, I have to check if at least one such value is greater than some known value 7.0, and if there is, I have to do "exit 1". I have to write this query in shell script.

Comment: Remove the `...` and post a valid JSON with proper values instead of `value1`, `value2` and an actual comparison

Comment: How do you plan to detect the value of "keyX" if it is unknown but there are other keys in the object? Are the other keys known and can be ignored? But please provide a [mre] with valid JSON (without `...`) and explain in more detail how "keyX" can be found if multiple keys exist in the object.

Comment: _I have to check if at least one such value is greater than some known value "limit"_ and do what? Print the number? Print a boolean status (true/false)?

Comment: @Inian The json which I want to parse is 8000 lines long that's why I posted a general structure

Comment: @Inian , knittl.  I have edited the question, please let me know if it's more understandable now

Comment: @AjaySabarish - The "m" in the [mcve] guidelines stands for minimal.  It would be very easy to construct a small JSON that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input is valid JSON in a file named input.json, then based on my understanding of the requirements, you could go with:

```
jq --argjson limit 7.0 '
  any(.. | select(type=="object" and (.base_score|type=="number")) | .base_score; . > $limit)
  | halt_error(if . then 1 else 0 end)
' input.json
```

You can modify the argument to `halt_error` to set the exit code as you wish.

Note that `halt_error` redirects its input to stderr, so you might want to append `2> /dev/null` (or the equivalent expression appropriate for your shell) to the above invocation.

Comment: What's the advantage of using `halt_error(if …)` over `jq -e` (assuming that true/false needs to be mapped to 0/1)?

Comment: @knittl - Yes, I mentioned it for the reasons stated. Also, combining the -e option with `exit 1` might be a bit tricky to get right under all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get a stream of `base_score` values at any level and use that with `any`:

```
any(..|.base_score?; . > 7)
```

The stream will contain `null` values for objects without the property, but null is not greater than any number, so that shouldn't be a stopper.

You could then compare the output or specify `-e`/`--exit-status` to be used with a condition directly:

```
jq -e 'any(..|.base_score?; . > 7)' complexnestedfile.json >/dev/null && exit 1
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but how to pass the JSON file as an argument to the above script ?

Comment: @AjaySabarish same as you always do: by feeding via stdin or by specifying the path the file. I have adapted by answer